# Android Notification - Popup dialog box

Tags: android, dialog, popup, notifications, android-alertdialog

i am trying to create a dialog box to appear in the middle of the screen when my main program is not in focus and running in background. The purpose of the dialog box is to force the user to take an immediate action.  I am already using the notification manager to notify the user but i would still like a old school popup dialog box.

Thanks :D

Comment: Hi user798869.. I am alos in the same position. Have you solved your problem.. If so please help me too.. Many thanks

Answer (score 3):

Popping up a dialog from an application running in the background is thought of as bad practice because it may confuse the user, and may annoy the user because you are disrupting the current task s/he is engaged in.

It is advised by the Android developers to use the Android notification system for tasks like these. A guide to create notifications is here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

Comment: Some apps like line can do that if the user want

Answer (score 0):

Dialogs are created with the Intent of the current activity. Since your app will not be in focus at the time, you cannot create a dialog.

Comment: But we can start new Activity with theme dialog. But the background Activity comes in foreground behind the Popup activity. How to resolve this?

Comment: yeah... that's exactly my point, you cannot do it without the background activity coming into foreground

Comment: But i am starting new Activity, why background activity coming into foreground thats my point? How can i stop if can?

Comment: Indeed. I have tried to initiate a new activity with transparent theme but the background activity will end up behind the new activity.   i wonder how those 3rd party SMS application with popup notification works.

Comment: Hi mvrck and user798869. I am also in need to popup message for alarm. I done it but ended up in background activity.. Are you guys solved that problem.. If so please help me.. thanks in advance

Comment: The background activity comes back because your new activity will be added on the existing task stack. I haven't tested this myself, but it may work - launch the new activity with the intent flag NEW_TASK. This should solve your problem